# In R, is there a fast way to simulation N binary variables with a common correlation?

Tags: r

I would like to simulate in R, N Bernoulli/Binary random variables with a prescribed correlation. I have been using the package (MultiOrd) with the function

`generate.binary`.

However, it is too slow. Is there a computationally fast way to do this in existing packages? Thanks.

Comment: Please show us the specific programming problem you have. A good way to do this is by creating an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: This question is not off topic. It does not ask to recommend an offsite resource. Rather, it asks for a faster way to perform a specific operation. Please reopen this question.

Comment: Those of you who voted to close this: You are actively working to make SO worse by closing perfectly good questions. This deprives SO users the opportunity to contribute helpful answers .Please stop doing that.

Comment: Thank you @Ista for understanding. It would indeed be great if they could re-open this question.